# Is there still a Night's Watch?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S08E03,

> the Night King was defeated.

In S08E06, we see that Jon is

> forced to live at Castle Black.

Does the Night's Watch still exist? If so, what is their purpose now? The dead are gone and the people north of where the wall used to be (the Free Folk) are Jon's friends.

Comment: Related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211454/are-the-nights-watch-still-required?noredirect=1#comment580702_211454

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the Night's Watch still exist? If so, what is their purpose now?

## Yes, the Night's Watch still exists.

Per Jon and Tyrion's conversation towards the end of S08E06.

> TYRION: So, the new King has chosen to send you to the Night's Watch.
> JON: There's still a Night's Watch?
> TYRION: The world will always need a home for bastards and broken men.