# What does the Nightwatch do now?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

We've seen before in *Game of Thrones* season 8 that the army of the dead and the white walkers are destroyed but in the season finale, Jon is sent to the wall to be a Nightwatch again.

But why does the Nightwatch still exist?

What exactly do they "watch"?

Comment: Strongly related: [Is there still a Night's Watch?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100895/49)

Comment: SFF: [Is Night's Watch still needed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211454/54887)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson There indeed IS a Nightwatch. they literally show it. but what's their point?

Comment: The premise of the question is quite similar, though.

Answer (score 4):

For quite some time people had ceased to seriously believe in White Walkers. During that time the Night's Watch continued to exist, serving two purposes:

1. Ward off Wildlings the best they can
2. Be a politically convenient dumping ground for criminals etc.

No reason it can't continue to do this.  The first one is all the more relevant now that there's a big hole in the wall. And there's a shot at good political relations with them now, which would transform the first into the political function of preserving and monitoring those relations.

Answer (score 2):

The White Walkers were thought to be a myth until they appeared in real life. The Night's Watch could defend against the possibility of other mythical creatures being real.

Tryion speaks of "Grumkins and Snarks".